# Importing Active Directory fields into User Profile Managed Metadata Properties

Tags: 2010, user-profile, managed-metadata, user-profile-service

In the simplest approach, we've created a term set for our company's departments. Our Active Directory also captures this information as a string property. When we import our users from AD into SharePoint, we want to map the Department value from AD into the SharePoint Managed Metadata field.

I know SharePoint has built in Managed Metadata Profile fields, but do they get imported from AD? We don't want our users to manually enter this information (nor change it).

Is this readily available and I've been mis-reading all the research I've been looking through, or is it really impossible (OOTB without code) to map an AD field into a Managed Metadata field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping is clearly defined in the UP-SA a lot being automatically defined and mapping too.

During setup of the connection in the User Profile you can change/update such mappings. When syncronization runs in the System termSet multiple terms are automatically created, including Job Title.

To use a managed metadata a field, you need to change the mapping of your properties (not all properties allow it, e.g. for Department you need to remove it prior to re-mapping it) and use the "Configure a Term Set to be used for this property" to reconfigure it.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks C:\Marius (love the name), it does help but Managed Metadata profile mapped fields are still a bit mysterious to me. What happens if the value in AD doesn't match up to a value in the term set while importing? Also, when using people search can we search on the mapped Profile Property, the term set, or both?

Comment: Turns out it will map to managed metadata -- all or nothing. Thanks for your help.